# Не получается взаимодействовать с shikimori api

Tags: javascript, api

Не могу обратиться к api, так как js выдает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать данную ошибку? Ниже приложу код

```
function sendAuth(method, url, body = null){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open(method, url)

        xhr.responseType = 'json'
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        xhr.onload = () => {
            if(xhr.status >= 400){
                resolve(xhr.response)
                alert('lol')
            } else {
                resolve(xhr.response)
            }
        }

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            reject(xhr.response)
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body))
    })
}
const body = {
User-Agent: 's’app',
grant_type: "authorization_code",
client_id: "its secret",
client_secret: "its secret to",
code: "AUTORIZATION_CODE",
redirect_uri: "https://sxndwl.xyz/s'stats",
}

sendAuth('POST', authURL, body)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты про синтаксическую ошибку, то возьми User-agent ключ в кавычки:

```
const body = {
  "User-Agent": 's’app',
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  client_id: "its secret",
  client_secret: "its secret to",
  code: "AUTORIZATION_CODE",
  redirect_uri: "https://sxndwl.xyz/s'stats",
}
```